# Как сделать версию сайта под Андроид?

Tags: php, html, css

Какие есть способы и средства для создания версии сайта для `Android` без знаний `javascript`? Может быть есть какие-то системы, типа `Wordpress` или `Drupal`? То же самое хотелось бы знать и про `iOS` и `Windows Phone`.

Comment: Версия сайта под андроид, будет дороже стоить чем обычная. При её создании, необходимо много трудозатрат и соответствующих знаний, что бы все правильно сделать. Какие то системы есть где автоматически все можно будет создать, но это будет - юпи, зуко, и прочая хрень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Версия сайта под ОС Android в конечном итоге у Вас должна зависеть от разрешения экрана конечного устройства (ведь HTML и JavaScript, в основном, будут работать нормально). Ваша задача - создать CSS для определенных устройств (по разрешению) и естественно предусмотреть меню, графику и пр. К сожалению "универсального" конвертера для сайтов я не встречал. Почитайте данную статью [здесь.](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=1077)

Comment: Спасибо, вы единственный умный человек, который нашел возможность ответить на мой вопрос.

Comment: Будьте так добры, подскажите, почему я задаю везде ширину 100%, а оно все равно на смартфоне отображает так, как будто я задаю прежние 800пкс? Не пойму, почему получается большой отступ от текста справа, а не текст во весь экран. Вот ссылка http://www.spravka-azov.ru/test/firm.php?id=657

А ВСЕ НАШЕЛ!

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/mobile/ - это чтобы просматривать обычный wordpress на мобильном устройстве
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/ - это собственно мобильная версия wordpress

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, конечно, но мой вопрос не в том. Мне нужно сделать мобверсию для существующего сайта, и я ищу какую-то систему, с помощью которой можно автоматически получить такую версию для уже имеющегося сайта. Вордпресс я привел как пример системы создания сайтов для людей не знающих языков програм-ния.